# how to intersect two associations in arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel

I have a project model w/ this association describing team members that have accepted (status)

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participants, :through => :team_members, :source => :user, :conditions => ['team_members.status = ?', TeamMember::STATUS[:accept]]
```

I have an activity model that has participants also

```
Class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :participants, :through => :collaborations, :source => :user
```

The activity participants which may include team members that haven't accepted yet. So, I want the intersection of these two associations. My goal is do 1 query, not repeat the sql of the association, and pluck a single column. I found Intersect described here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager#intersect-instance_method and was trying to infer its usage from https://github.com/rails/arel/commit/74caeaad157e79853b9c6804f561d3c70eea2346. But I'm having no luck.

The best I've got so far is to:

```
a = Activity.find(1)
team = a.project.participants.select('user_id').to_sql
peeps = a.participants.where("user_id in (#{team})")
peeps.pluck('thecolumn')
```

This does one query (good), doesn't repeat the logic of the association (good) and doesn't load up all the AR objects as I'm just after one value (good). However, I was hoping to be able to:

```
a = Activity.find(1)
peeps = a.project.particpants.intersect a.project.participants
```

which works, but returns an Arel::Nodes::Intersect... not sure how to grab the results from that.

Comment: no, still using the .to_sql :/

Comment: See my question and how I made it work for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320469/how-to-write-activerecord-arel-intersection-query/24323622#24323622

Answer (score 0):

Since the Arel supports to_sql you can do:

```
a = Activity.find(1)
peeps = a.project.particpants.intersect a.project.participants #(sic)
Participant.find_by_sql(["SELECT participants.* FROM #{peeps.to_sql}", ...])
```

But instead of intersecting with itself, I think you meant:

```
a = Activity.find(1)
peeps = a.particpants.intersect a.project.participants
Participant.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM #{peeps.to_sql}", ...])
```

You'll need to provide the parameters to the query.

I've also had success doing things like this to get a relation

```
PublicActivity::Activity.from("(#{activities.to_sql} UNION #{task_activities.to_sql}) as activities").order("created_at DESC")
```